# is it possible to have multiple modules defined in tsconfig?

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

Ok, so I'm making a angular2 app with a node server. I've followed the [5min tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) so I'm using "system" as the module system. However I am using a simple node express server instead of the way they have in the tutorial. I am writing this in typescript as well, but it is also compiled to "system" style of importing modules. And when running the server I get `System is not defined`.

- How do I fix so System is defined when starting the server?
- Is it not recommended to use "system" as the compiler option "module" in the tsconfig-file, when writing a node server?
- Can I compile the server code with eg "commonjs" and the angular front end with "system"?
- How do I do the configuration of module loading (the small script they have in the index.html) if I would not use "system" in the front end either?

Comment: can u post part of code where you are facing error

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to split front-end and back-end applications into different projects and make them communicate through a REST service. I mean the server application will provide the service and the front application will consume it using AJAX.

This way you will be sure that there won't be conflict between the tools you use. For example the use or not of SystemJS. You'll be free to use SystemJS in the Angular2 application as described in the 5min tutorial of the angular.io website and commonjs for the Node / Express application.

The following article describes how to do that:

- Angular2 TypeScript Gulp and ExpressJS - http://blog.edenmsg.com/angular2-typescript-gulp-and-expressjs/

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easier solution than separate in different projects.. currently the express server is only providing the files, so it's very small. Also I'm using webstorms built in compile on save, wasn't planning on using gulp for that anytime soon.. Having SystemJs for the express code is not a good idea, you think?

Answer (score 1):

As @Thierry Templier suggested, you need to split your code into /client and /server to be more maintainable and structured, if you didn't do that yet.

You can create two tsconfig.json files, put one into /server and other into /client folder.

- /server

  - tsconfig.json ( with module: commonjs )
- /client

  - tsconfig.json ( with module: systemjs )

When you are invoking tsc from shell, you use --project command:

```
tsc -p ./server <-- /server/tsconfig.json is loaded
tsc -p ./client <-- /client/tsconfig.json is loaded
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe I need to do this and not use webstorms built in. Currently I'm using the built in compile on save and I specify the tsconfig in the settings. As far as I know you can't set muliple tsconfigs.

Comment: Yes, i see that now. You have tow options: to start with custom build tools or to write express in plain js.